# editing a role icon in discord.py returns an error, any idea why?

Tags: discord.py

```py
@bot.command(name='role')
async def role(ctx, role_id, new_icon_url):

    new_icon_url = str(new_icon_url)
    if new_icon_url.count('<:') != 0:
        new_icon_url = new_icon_url.split(':')
        new_icon_url = new_icon_url[2]
        new_icon_url = new_icon_url.replace('>', '')
        new_icon_url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/%{placeholder}%.png'.replace('%{placeholder}%', new_icon_url)

    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=int(role_id))

    if role is not None:
        try:
            await role.edit(display_icon=new_icon_url)
            await ctx.send(f"Role icon for {role.name} has been updated.")
        except discord.errors.Forbidden:
            await ctx.send("I don't have the required permissions to edit role icons.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Role with ID {role_id} not found.")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VosQu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\VosQu\OneDrive\Desktop\Brewy Poo\brew.py", line 271, in role
    new_icon_url = bytes(new_icon_url)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VosQu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\VosQu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\VosQu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

I was expecting it to change the role icon, but instead it just returned back an error.

Comment: You should have a look to [the documentation here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit), you can't pass a link/url to `display_icon`, you need a bytes-like object or a unicode emoji.

Comment: I see in the error message `new_icon_url = bytes(new_icon_url)` but I can find this line in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because the `discord.py` module expects you to pass a `bytes` object to the `display_icon` parameter, not a string containing an image url.

A more appropriate way to develop your command is to receive an image file (attached to the command message):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


@bot.command(name='roleicon')
async def role_icon(ctx: commands.Context, role: discord.Role, new_icon: discord.Attachment):
    try:
        await role.edit(display_icon=await new_icon.read())
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.reply("I don't have the required permissions to edit role icons.")
    else:
        await ctx.reply(f"Role icon for {role.name} has been updated.")
```

Notes:

> - Instead of receiving a role id, use `role: discord.Role` and the library will do the automatic conversion. This parameter notation also allows the user to enter a name or mention of a role;
> - It is good programming practice to type your variables. This will enable your IDE to carry out inspections of your code and point out possible errors.

Answer (score -1):

As the error says you need to pass in an encoding system along with the string. For example using `utf-8` as our encoding system, it will look like `bytes(url, "utf-8")`